# Efficient count query in largeish database?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Django 1.7 app with a Postgres 9.3 backend. My database has around 400m rows of spending items, each with an associated organisation. The models are as follows:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=9, primary_key=True, db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SpendingItem(models.Model):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation)
    total_items = models.IntegerField() ... plus other info attached
```

I am now writing a view for each organisation that returns the total number of spending items attached. For large result sets it is very slow, e.g. more than 150 seconds for a query returning 1m results.

This is the view code:

```
def organisation(request, org_code):
    org = get_object_or_404(Organisation, code=org_code)
    num_spending_items = SpendingItem.objects.filter(organisation=org).count()
    context = {
        'organisation': org,
        'num_spending_items': num_spending_items
    }
    return render(request, 'organisation.html', context)
```

I've been reading the [Postgres documentation on slow counting](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting), but I'm wondering if there is anything simple I can do e.g. with indexes to speed things up, or whether I'll need to fall back to raw SQL and use some of the techniques mentioned in the docs. Or pre-generate the results and store them elsewhere.

My database table for spending items already has the following indexes, though I've been loading data with `COPY` statements, so I don't know if they're up to date (and not sure how I tell):

```
=# \d frontend_spendingitem;
                                       Table "public.frontend_spendingitem"
      Column       |          Type           |                             Modifiers
-------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                 | not null default nextval('frontend_spendingitem_id_seq'::regclass)
 total_items       | integer                 | not null
 organisation_id   | character varying(9)    | not null
Indexes:
    "frontend_spendingitem_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "frontend_spendingitem_a69d813a" btree (organisation_id)
    "frontend_spendingitem_organisation_id_4619f68f65c49a8_like" btree (organisation_id varchar_pattern_ops)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "front_organisation_id_4619f68f65c49a8_fk_frontend_organisation_code" FOREIGN KEY (organisation_id) REFERENCES frontend_organisation(code) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: Your indexes are always up-to-date. You might want to `ANALYZE` after a bulk load so the planner knows the distribution of data. You'll probably need to supply EXPLAIN ANALYSE or at least the query you are running if you want performance help.